# SQL excluding weekend days from date pull

Tags: sql, database, date, mdm

I am trying to extract dates which are 2 days after the current date, unless in the case that two days after the current date would be a weekend, in which case I am lookig for dates that are 4 days after the current date. I am using Data Studio and none of the sql functions (like dateadd) work on it.

I know I can get the dates I want using this pull:

```
select event_end_date from mdmins11.contract where event_end_date between (current date +1.9 days) and (current date + 2.1 days);
```

But this does not exclude the weekends. I was trying to do it mathematically as such:

```
select event_end_date
case(
when (current date + 2 days) = ('2014-09-06' + (7 days * int)) or ('2014-09-07' + (7 days * int))
then set @w = (current date + 4 days)
else set @w = (current date + 2 days)
)
from mdmins11.contract where event_end_date = @w;
```

Here I am trying to find the dates that are after Saturdays and Sundays in case (current date + 2) lands on a weekend. This is not working at all. Does anyone have any idea how to do this on sql without using the functions? I appriciate that my date formatting might be wrong but I am finding it hard to see the solution.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle...?

Comment: this is the IBM MDM system

Comment: Ah that's confusing `[mdm]` means `Mobile Device Management` over here, slightly misleading, seems there is no tag for this ibm technology yet?

Comment: Does this boil down to "select the weekday that's two weekdays from today"?

Comment: Not familiar with IBM MDM. Can you create tables or use common table expressions?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer! For anyone who is in the same situation:

```
select dayofweek(current date) as day_number,
   event_end_date 
from   mdmins11.contract 
where  (dayofweek(event_end_date) = 6 /*Friday*/
and    date(event_end_date) < current_date + 3 days
and    date(event_end_date) >= current_date)
or     (dayofweek(event_end_date) in (1,2,3,4,5,7) /*All other days of week*/
and    date(event_end_date) < current_date + 2 days
and    date(event_end_date) >= current_date)

;
```

If you happen to have a list of holiday dates, you can also incorporate this in.